# Problem about positive definite Hermitian form

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V_{1},V_{2}$ be finite dimensional complex vector space and $V=V_{1}\oplus V_{2}$.
Let $h_{1},h_{2}$ be Hermitian forms on $V$ satisfying

(1) $\forall v_{i}\neq0\in V_{i} ,\; h_{i}(v_{i},v_{i})>0  \;(i=1,2)$.

(2) $x=x_{1}+x_{2},y=y_{1}+y_{2}, \, (x_{i},y_{i}\in V_{i}) \implies h_{2}(x,y)=h_{2}(x_{2},y_{2}). $

I want show that there exist $\lambda>0$ such that $h_{1}+\lambda h_{2}$ is a positive definite Hermitian form on $V.$ How to prove it?

Comment: The only way (1) and (2) can simultaneously be true is if $V_1 = \{0\}$. Because if $x_1 \in V_1$, then since $x_1 = x_1 + 0$, we have by (2) that $h_2(x_1, x_1) = h_2(0,0) = 0$. Therefore by (1) $x_1 = 0$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair (1) don't imply $x_{1} = 0$ because $x_{1}\in V_{1} , not\in V_{2}$